# How can I add a a default server Block in Nginx?

Tags: web-services, nginx, mongoose-web-server

I have several sites configured in Nginx and I was wondering if I can include a default configuration for all of them in a single server Block and then include that  in the sites server block.

For example if I want to set security directives which is common to all sites, then it would nice If I can include it in one server Block rather than having to modify every sites server block.

Let me know the best possible way to tackle this

Comment: You could put repeating config to a file and `include` that file wherever you want.

Comment: @AlexeyTen Can't I Just add it to main http block?

Comment: It depends on what directives you want

Comment: @AlexeyTen can I add the location directives inside the http block?

Comment: Read the docs http://nginx.org/r/location Context: server, location

Comment: @AlexeyTen Thanks, looks like I ll have to add it for every server block